# How do I pass data between views in Oracle JET?

Tags: oracle-jet

I'm working on an Oracle JET application with the `navbar` template, and the application gets data from a REST API. On the main view `interfaces.html`, we have an `oj-table` displaying a summary of all interfaces based on data fetched from the REST API. On clicking a link on the `interfaceId` column of the table, the application navigates to a new view `interfaceDetails.html` which displays further details on the interafce.

Currently, I'm passing the data to the `interfaceDetails.html` view via `observable`s declared in `appController.js`, which gets the specific interface data from the selected row in in `interfaces.html` via a selection listener. However, I'd like to redesign the API in the `interface.html` view to only provide summary data, and have another API called from `interfaceDetails.html`'s view model to fetch details of for the specific interface.

I'm using this selection listener to get the selected row in the table:

```
self.interfaceList= ko.observableArray();

//
//REST API calls, table data source setup, etc.
//

self.interfacesTblSelctionListener = function(event) {
    var interfaceId = null;
    event.detail.value.row.values().forEach(key => {
        interfaceId = key;
    });

    if(interfaceId != undefined) {
        $.each(self.interfaceList(), function(id, integration) {
            if(integration.INTERFACE_ID == interfaceId) {
                app.selectedIntegration(integration);
                self.serviceList(integration.Services);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And I'm using this function to move between views:

```
self.openIntegrationDetailsView = function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    self.router = oj.Router.rootInstance;
    self.router.go('interfaceDetails');
    });
}
```

Is there a way to pass on minimal data (e.g. the interface ID) to the `interfaceDetails` view and have that fetch details on its own?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Debojit

P.S. Apologies if my query isn't clear enough; this is my first JET application. Please let me know if additional information is required and I'll update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checkout [this](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=corerouter&demo=parameters) example of core-router where we are passing employee index as an argument to the detail page via `router.go` and fetching the employee detail when we land into that page (ofcourse, in your app you would be doing s Rest call to get the data)

```
this.router.go({ path: 'employee-detail', params: { index: indices[0] } });
```

Comment: Hi, I'm looking at the example, and I'm afraid I'm a little confused. If I;m reading the example correctly, the functionality seems to hinge largely on the call to the function `this.initialize`, but I can't exactly spot where that happens. Could you elaborate a little, please.
Thanks,

Comment: thats a lifecycle method which gets called automatically. look for initialize() here => https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet410/jet/developer/GUID-858030A0-D7B3-49B0-B2C6-BC1294E5991A.htm#JETDG-GUID-ABB82BD1-9B65-44D2-AE43-81A0A3A44453

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot!!